# I want touchpad-like behaviour on an Apple Magic Mouse on Linux

Tags: mouse, touchpad, apple

I run Linux (Ubuntu 14.4) on a mid 2010 iMac 27". The hardware support is mostly great but I would like to use my Apple bluetooth mouse ("magic mouse") in a touchpad-fashioned way. Right after installation I could connect this mouse but the touch function works mostly just like an old-fashioned mouse wheel. Which means that I can "scroll" up and down and after about each centimeter my browser window (for example) will move a portion (the portion like when I hit the up/down arrows on the keyboard).

On OSX the browser on the other hand scrolls pixel by pixel with the slightest movement of your finger on the mouse.

Any hints?